# efficient way to prepare time series with sliding window (save&read or make data every itr)

Tags: python, time-series, chunks, memory-efficient, dataloader

Time-series data have dimensions below
C: Channel
L: Length of time(sequence)

I have L is over 200000 and C is over 200.

In dataloader, data are

```
def __getitems(self, idx):
 return  data # data=(B, C, W), B:Batch size, W=sliding window size
```

The original data size is approximately

> 20^5*200*3(float32) = 120Mb.
> But, I need a large sliding window such as over 512, then the data size with rolling window is
> 10^5 * 2*10^2 * 2^8* 3(float32) [byte] = 3*2^9*10^2 =60Gb

There are several ways to prepare data

1. Save and Load

- split the data into a small size and make rolling window data

  ```
    div = d1*d2*self.ls *3 // (1024*1024*1024) #1GB
    len_chunck = d1//div //self.save_batch * self.save_batch
    setL = 0
    for k in tqdm(range(div), desc=f"data gen... idx={i+1}/{len(self.set_info)}") :
        data_split = data[k*len_chunck:(k+1)*len_chunck+self.ls]
        div_data = torch.Tensor(to_roll_window(data_split, self.ls).astype(float))
        div_data = div_data[:div_data.shape[0]//self.save_batch*self.save_batch]
        L, self.C, self.T = div_data.shape
        for j, idx in enumerate(range(0, L, self.save_batch)):
            #save it into the storage
            fname = f'{i}_{j+setL:04d}.npy' #save it into the storage
            np.save(os.path.join(self.data_basepath, fname), div_data[idx:idx+self.save_batch])
  ```
- but, it needs lots of **reading time**

2. make data at every getitem() in dataloader

   def **getitem**(self, idx):
   d = torch.Tensor(np.empty([B, C, W]))
   for j, i in enumerate(idx):
   d[j] = self.data_transposed[:, i:i+W]

#data = (L, C)
#data_transposed = transposed data (C, L)

I think the second way is more efficient, but it also consumes time...

Is there any fancy way to solve this problem?